# Where do I find the full list of permissions for Android by API level?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

as the title suggests, I fail to find any list that contains a full list of Android permissions by API level. When I find some list online, they cite their source as [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), which only consists of an overview of permissions.

I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) list, which I'm guessing includes all permissions, but it is huge, and it just denotes when the permission was added. But some permissions were removed on Android, after version 6.0, protection levels of numerous permissions were changed. Depending on API level, the permission list can vary greatly. Therefore I cannot see anything that is helpful to me. I am new on Android platform, but I can't even find a proper documentation for the version releases, I am just confused.

Does what I ask exist?

Comment: Android Developers. Or Android Open Source.

Comment: The mentioned list also denotes the deprecated permissions

Comment: But it doesn't mention when it was deprecated, or it doesn't show if one permission had a different protection level before etc. It isn't useful for me, it isn't what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Depending on API level, the permission list can vary greatly.

The permission list is mostly additive. Permissions are only infrequently removed or have their `protectionLevel` altered. Which permission group a permission belongs to also can change, but that should not have any impact on your own code. For the vast majority of developers, for the vast majority of scenarios, just knowing when a permission was added to the platform is sufficient.

The source code is the "source of truth" regarding permission definitions for an OS version. They appear as `<permission>` elements in the platform manifest, as permissions are declared for the platform much the same way as custom permissions are declared in an app's manifest. Here is the platform manifest for Android 11:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Scroll down to find the `<permission>` elements ([here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml;l=685-692) is the first one, for `READ_CONTACTS`). You can use the second drop-down in the breadcrumbs row towards the top to switch to a different branch/OS version — to [Android 9.0](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-9.0.0_r1:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), for example.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to answer my question. I think I should've mentioned that I'm not really developing a single app, but using this list to analyze the difference between versions before and after 6.0.